# fragment.isVisible() returns true when app is running in background

Tags: android, fragment

I could not find an answer to this question.

In my app, `fragment.isVisible()` returns true, if my app is closed via Home Button. Is this the standard behavior or should I expect this not always to be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick

```
public boolean isFragmentUIActive() {
    return isAdded() && !isDetached() && !isRemoving();
}
```

Now i invisible when your app is in background